# View count for blog post. ASP.NET WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

A few days ago, i create my little project. This project is my personal blog. He based on ASP.NET WebAPI (back-end), Angular (front-end).

My `Post` entity have `ViewCount` field.

How to calculate the number of post views? And that at restart (F5), the counter does not increase.

Is there a ready-made piece of code or implementation tips?

Thanks to everyone who responds.

Comment: don't vampire for code

Comment: Oh, sorry, because think about this task more than 2 days. Maybe you know how to do this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create something on your own as your question too broad, but generally speaking, you'll need to update your `Post` entity in your action each time it's hit. For example:

```
post.ViewCount++;
db.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

However, there's a number of things to take into consideration:

1. You'll need to plan for concurrency issues (i.e., multiple simultaneous requests attempting to update the view count at the same time). To do that, you'll need to catch and respond to `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` when saving.

   ```
   try
   {
       db.SaveChanges();
   }
   catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
   {
       // handle it
   }
   ```

   There's various strategies for how to handle concurrency. [Microsoft details your options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592904(v=vs.113).aspx). However, simply handling it once, may not be enough as the next save could also cause a concurrency exception, and so on. I'd recommend employing something like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly), which gives you far more powerful exception handling abilities, including retrying a number of times or forever.
2. You'll need to weed out duplicate requests (From an F5 refresh, for example). To do that, you'll likely want to set something in the user's session, such as an access time, and then only count the view if it's been some determined amount of time since the user last accessed the page, or the key doesn't exist in their session (first view). Bear in mind session timeouts with this though. For example, if you only want to count a view for a user every hour, but your session times out after 20 minutes, that's not going to work. In that scenario, you'd want to store the access time some place more persistent, like a database table. If you do use the session, you should also use a SQL Server or Redis backing for your session state, rather than In Proc or State Server, since the former will be much more reliable than the latter.
3. You'll need to take into account bots. This could be any automated viewing of the page, benign or malicious. At the very least, you'll want to account for spiders like GoogleBot, so you don't increment the view count every time your site gets indexed. However, trying to determine if a request originates from a bot or not, is a whole thing in itself. Entire databases of bot UA strings are managed explicitly to try to track what's out in the wild. It's achievable to exclude at least a vast majority of automated traffic, but your view count will basically be as accurate as you are about filtering bots out.

Based on all that, unless you have a *really* good reason you actually need to track the view count yourself, I'd say don't worry about it. For example, if you're just trying to report internally on usage statistics, employing something like Google Analytics, will be a far easier and more manageable solution. Even if you do need the view count for something in your application, it still may be better to install third-party analytics software locally. Look for a solution with an API or at least some way to get at the data programmatically, and then you can simply pull the view count from that.